# regex javascript remove string that follows/precedes/delimits another string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello regex experts!

Question One
I want to find the sub string 'delimiter' and remove it as well as anything following it
so the result is 'fredrobert'

```
var originalstring = 'fredrobertdelimitergarysusan';
var result = orig.match(/* not sure what goes here*/);              
console.log('result = ',result); //fredrobert
```

Question Two
I want to find the sub string 'delimiter' and remove it as well as anything preceding it
so the result is 'garysusan'

```
var originalstring = 'fredrobertdelimitergarysusan';
var result = orig.match(/* not sure what goes here*/);              
console.log('result = ',result); //garysusan
```

Question Three
I want to find the sub strings 'delimiterA' and 'delimiterB' remove them as well as what is betweenso the result is 'fredsusan'

```
var originalstring = 'freddelimiterArobertgarydelimiterBsusan';
var result = orig.match(/* not sure what goes here*/);              
console.log('result = ',result);  //fredsusan
```

Comment: You could use the string-indexing function for a couple of these and search for the substring `delimiter`, then take a substring either up to or after that location (plus `delimiter` length).  For the third one, consider `/^(.*?)delimiter.*delimiter(.*?)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use `.replace()`, not `.match()`. `.match()` finds text that matches a pattern, but doesn't replace it. `.replace()`, well, it replaces it!

**Question One**

Use .replace(), not .match():

```
var originalstring = 'fredrobertdelimitergarysusan';
var result = orig.replace(/delimiter.*/, '');              
console.log('result = ',result); //fredrobert
```

**Question Two**

Again, use .replace():

```
var originalstring = 'fredrobertdelimitergarysusan';
var result = orig.replace(/.*delimiter/, '');
console.log('result = ',result); //garysusan
```

**Question Three**

Use .replace() with `.*` between delimiters:

```
var originalstring = 'freddelimiterArobertgarydelimiterBsusan';
var result = orig.replace(/delimiterA.*delimiterB/, '');              
console.log('result = ',result);  //fredsusan
```

Comment: excellent, this works. here is the jsfiddle of this [http://jsfiddle.net/s7H9v/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/s7H9v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Match the word "delimiter" and everything after it, to the end of the string:

```
/delimiter.*$/
```

"delimiter" and everything preceding it:

```
/^.*delimiter/
```

"delimiterA," "delimiterB" and everything between:

```
/delimiterA.*delimiterB/
```

Comment: this didn't work see this jsfiddle and watch console [link](http://jsfiddle.net/s7H9v/)